# Thevenin equivalent voltage

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage

I am trying to find the Thevenin equivalent of the following circuit:

[image: A circuit diagram. The outside loop goes, in clockwise order, from voltage source V to resistor R to point A, there is then a gap to point B, then to current source I and back to the voltage source. There is also a resistor R in parallel to the current source.]

In regards to the equivalent voltage, I know (I have the answers) that it should be V + IR, but I am not sure how to get there. This is what I have so far, where R1 is the resistor between the voltage source and A, and R2 is the other resistor (in parallel with the current source):

Using KVL on the loop V-->R-->A-->B-->R-->V,
$$V=I_{R1}R+V_{out}+I_{R2}R$$
Using KCL on the node that joins the current source, the resistor and the voltage source:
$$I+I_{R2}=I_{R1}$$

However, I need another equation to be able to solve these, as I currently have three unknowns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: to find equivalent resistance replace all ideal voltage sources with short circuits and all ideal current sources with open circuits.

Hope this helps

Comment: Do you know how I would go about finding the equivalent voltage?

Comment: You already did. Convert current source in parallel with R  to voltage source equal to IR in series with R. This gives you a Thevenin voltage of IR+V in series with 2R which is the Thevenin resistance

Answer (score 0):

Convert the current source and its parallel resistor from Norton to Thevenin form.

Now you have two Thevenin circuits in series and it's very easy to combine them into a single Thevenin equivalent.